# Where does eclipse search for a file if full path is not provided?

Tags: eclipse

In NetBeans (Java Application Project) if I put a file in the root directory of a project NetBeans can find the file. For example

```
FileReader reader = new FileReader(new File("test.txt"));
```

Here test.txt file is in the root directory of the project. This is what the root directory look like. 
-> Project Folder 
--> build 
--> nbproject 
--> src 
--> test 
--> build.xml 
--> manifest.mf 
--> **test.txt**

I have tried putting a file in the root directory of an eclipse dynamic web project with the same code. But it cannot find the file. This is what the root directory for eclipse looks like. 
-> Project Folder 
--> .settings 
--> build 
--> src 
--> .classpath 
--> .project 
--> **test.txt** 
**In which location does eclipse search for files by default? Is it different for different types of projects?**

Comment: In the classpath. `src` or `resources` usually

Comment: Do I have to add it to classpathentry?

Answer (score 2):

The root of the project is not deployed to the server, plus you can not rely on the "working directory" being anything other than what the server chooses for your application. Place the text file under the `src/main/java` or `src/main/webapp` folder and read the file's contents using your Servlet class' `#getResourceAsStream(String)` or current Servlet context using `ServletContext#getResourceAsStream()`, respectively.